# Eslint reporting in VSCode but not on the terminal

Tags: eslint, prettier, eslintrc

I'm using es-lint VScode extension and it is catching 5 linting errors, however when I run npm run lint from `package.json` It only lists 2 errors. I'm wondering why the terminal is not outputting all linting errors, so I can fix it with `esw --fix` on save.

Note: I'm using both prettier and airbnb config rules.

Here is my `.eslintrc`:

```
{
  "extends": ["airbnb", "prettier"],
  "plugins": ["prettier"],
  "globals": { "document": false }
}
```

Here is `pacjakge.json`:

```
 {
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "styled-components": "^2.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint --fix ./src",
    "watch:lint": "node_modules/eslint-watch/bin/esw -w --fix"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.12.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^2.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.5.1",
    "eslint-watch": "^3.1.3",
    "prettier": "^1.9.1"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `--fix` option when running `npm run lint`, that means ESLint will only display errors/warnings it can't fix automatically.. everything else, it will just fix and not complain about.

If you want it to list all the errors/warning, you can remove `--fix` from your NPM script, and it will list all erros/warnings it finds (it will run `eslint ./src`). Later if you want to fix the errors as well, run `npm run lint -- --fix`, that will pass everything after `--` directly to the script, i.e., will run `eslint ./src --fix` which will work correctly.